# select2 overwrites e.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, jquery-select2

I've wrote a script which uses a bunch of data and building a grid where you are able to move through with the arrowkeys and tab.

While testing it in a seperate file everything works fine. After adding it to my Website the script works pretty well in Chrome, Opera, Safari and IE. But in Firefox my focus jumps out of the grid and went to the adressbar. Using the same Data in my testfile, there is no error like this.

What could be a reason why it does not work in Firefox? I got no Errors in Firebug.

Its a file with more then 2500 lines...Here is the part where the navigation with Tab starts:

```
    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
                switch (e.keyCode) {
                    case 9:
                        if (editing == true) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            var direction = "right";
                            if (e.shiftKey) {
                                direction = "left";
                            }
                            root.gridSave();
                            root.moveMark(direction);
                            var checker = true;
                            var c = 0;
                            while (checker) {
                                if (!clickTarget) {
                                    if (newLine == true) {
                                        root.markNewLineFirstCell();
                                        root.scrollVert();
                                    } else {
                                        root.moveMark("right");
                                    }
                                }
                                if (!clickTarget.hasClass("editable")) {
                                    root.moveMark(direction);
                                    if (c > root.captions.length) {
                                        checker = false;
                                    }
                                    c++;
                                } else {
                                    editMode = false;
                                    root.edit(clickTarget);
                                    root.setFocus(clickTarget);
                                    checker = false;
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            if (editMode == true) {
                                direction = "right";
                                if (e.shiftKey) {
                                    direction = "left";
                                }
                                root.moveMark(direction);
                                root.scrollVert();
                            }
                        }
                        break;
}
});
```

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: Hope you could work with this

Comment: ok found a solution. The main reason is that firefox got some problems with the keydown event. if i use keypress everything works fine